# How to get current location update every 10 steps moved

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have implemented this code to get current location update every 10 steps moved but I'm not getting current lat lng as i move 10 steps or more, I have question is it realistic to set minimum distance 10 steps?

Also every time when my code runs I get different different lat lng in terms of digits after decimal and if i compare these lat lng that i get every time my application runs with current location on google maps website, its roughly 400 meters away from my current location, why is it happening.

```
 private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private TextView tvLat;
private TextView tvLng;
Map<String, Double> latlng = new HashMap<>();
DatabaseReference data;
private double lat;
private double lng;

CameraPosition CurrentLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SingletonConnectClass instence =   SingletonConnectClass.getInstance();
    data = instence.firebaseSetup();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    initView();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

mFusedLocationClient 
 = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

   mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    getCurrentLocation();
    buildClient();
}

private void getCurrentLocation(){
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
   CurrentLocation = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new 
                          LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                                location.getLongitude()))
                                .zoom(15.5f)
                                .bearing(0)
                                .tilt(25)
                                .build();
      //changed camera position to current location and added marker there
    }
```

Here is the code for getting current location update if i move 10 steps after connecting to play services in onConnected callback

```
 public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(requestLocation(),
    new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (final Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

                //not getting changing current lat lng if i move 10 steps
                tvLat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
                tvLng.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();

                //as result not camera position is not changed
                changeCameraPosition(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLong)

                    }}, Looper.myLooper());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            //Place current location marker
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

            //stop location updates
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what Am i missing in my code? onLocationChanged? do I have to manually implement onLocationChanged?

Comment: then what requestLocationUpdates do?